# How to integrate additional login types in SingleOrg MVC ASP.NET Core Web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am developing ad asp.net core mvc web application that requires a login using an active directory for account of an organization . I did that with using SingleOrg but what I Need to do is:

**1- I want to add also a login using other methods like facebook or google which are usually used using individual user.**

**2- In individual login a database is created that saves tokens and users but with azure active directory login this is not done why?.**

Answer (score 0):

You can add Multiple authentication providers feature to your application to serve the purpose.

For that you have to do the followings:

- [Use `SecretManager` to store tokens assigned by login providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows)
- Setup different login providers (Facebook, AD etc.)

> ```
> services.AddAuthentication()
>     .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions => { ... })
>     .AddGoogle(googleOptions => { ... })
>     .AddTwitter(twitterOptions => { ... })
>     .AddFacebook(facebookOptions => { ... });
> ```

- Implement the authentication providers

Here are the [detail steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: when creating an application using individual user a database is automatically created and insert of users to the databases is also automatically done. So is there any way i can add this feature to the organization identity where the app automatically create and store the tokens and users. Thank YOU